# Best practices and architecture for SPA

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, architecture, single-page-application

I realise this may be an opinion based question, but I am am curious if there are any best practices regarding setting up a new SPA in Visual Studio.

I have some experience with TypeScript, Knockout, Underscore, Moment, Razor and MVC4 framework (and EF6).

What interest me the most is:
-Is there a VS SPA template that is considered "the best" or do I start from scratch?
-What kind of projects and naming conventions should i use in VS?
-What libraries is considered as good combinations in SPA (Angular.js is something I'm looking into) ?
-What is consideres best practices regarding client call to retrieve data from a database (first and foremost Ajax call)
-Best practices regarding HTML/CSS coding

Do you know about about a tutorial or documentation that you have used and found very helpful on the subject(s) and that is regarded as a "must read"?

Maybe somethings in the lines of this:
http://isobar-idev.github.io/code-standards/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605877.aspx

**UPDATE (what I learned so far):**

Client:

- Ember or AngularJS for main framework
- TypeScript and DefinatelyTyped for getting type completion
- If Angular: Drop RequireJS as it does not play along with Angular  -> http://developer.telerik.com/featured/requiring-vs-browerifying-angular/
- Lo-dash (replacement for underscore -> [Differences between lodash and underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore))
- Ditch the Razor view engine as it does not play very well with Angular -> [Razor templates, views and angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262309/razor-templates-views-and-angular-js)
- Moment.js (for handling dates -> http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/momentjs-simplifies-working-with-date-values-in-javascript/)

Client-Server communication:

- Breeze for quering the server for data and exhange of metadata(?)  -> http://www.breezejs.com/
- SignalR (under consideration as I am building a forum/chat system in my webapp)
- Websockets (if I need realtime solutions...)

Server:

- Asp.Net WebApi for HTTP services
- EF 6 (for creating entities)

Database:

- SQL server express for now (for ease of entity generation), other suggestions?

VS directory structure and project definitions:

- Not sure about this yet..

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs

Comment: Thanks for the link @OrenA! WebApi seems like a good way  to handle request from the client. I'll try to summarize my findings on the internet in the main post

Comment: If you like knockout you should try out Durandal.
Typescript is a must.
About project structure...
Keep the website in a seporate project from the server (within the same solution thoug).
Breeze is nice for data display and caching, but for security reasons I would recomend updates to be performed by simple api calls using custom Business Objects.